# How to sort Array by order of dependent each other

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I know the title is quite hard to understand.

I'll simply explain by simple code below.

```js
var objA = {
    id: 1
}
var objB = {
    id: 2,
    children: [1,3] //<== this is ID of objA and objC
}
var objC = {
    id: 3,
    children: [1] //<== this is ID of objA
}

function myFunction(){
    const list = [objA, objB, objC];
    // Do something to sort to [objA, objC, objB]
    var listSorted = ...;
    for(var item in listSorted){
        //Do something else
    }
}
```

In the demo code above, the `objA` is independent of any other, so it should be run first, the `objB` depends on `objA` and `objC` so it should be run after `objA` and `objC`, and so on.
So after sorting the `list`, it should be to `[objA, objC, objB]`

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? Like sorting by length of `children`, ...

Comment: @Andreas no, it shouldn't work correctly because maybe the same length of children as other

Comment: Yes, it's just the first step. But right now you don't show any attempt at all - not even the first step.

Comment: Is a dependency cycle possible? e.g. objA depends on objB and objB depends on objA.

Comment: @HeikoRibberink no, I make sure that couldn't happened

Comment: @Andreas I tried to research and test so much, but have no result

Comment: I don't know an algorithm from the top of my head. But what you do know, is that every item depending on another item, should be put after that other item. If this constraint is met for every item, it should work. Using this, you could implement a comparator for your item and use a standard sorting algorithm.

Comment: Looks like a kind of tree to me. There are enough algorithms to traverse trees.

Comment: @HeikoRibberink I couldn't. My demo code is just a simple demo. In the real case, it's unsorted

Comment: @RalfRenz any idea like pseudo-code? I really appreciate it. 
P/s: it may not be a kind of tree, because it maybe has more than one doesn't depend on any other

Comment: Who voted close to my question? Please give me a reason?

Comment: I didn't vote to close the question, but I guess the reason is that you're asking a very broad question and not showing an exact issue with something concrete. Which I disagree on, that's why I didn't vote to close. But it's true that you didn't show any attempt so the question becomes a bit broad. I agree with @RalfRenz, it looks like a tree (a directed graph I would say), and there are tons of algorithms for tree traversal.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ thank you for your explanation. But after research, I think the algorithm of tree traversal doesn't help in my case. Have a nice day

Comment: I would try it maybe like this: first take all objects without a dependency. Best put them in a set. Next choose all the objects with dependencies only in the set (and add them to the set). And so on.

Comment: That's surprising, I think you don't see the link because you didn't put them into a graph yet, but they're clearly structured as a tree. Also, I think there's an issue with your data. You say that B depends on 1 (A) and 3 (C) and at the same time 3 (C) depends on 1 (A). Does it mean simply that 2 (B) depends on 3 (C) (since C couldn't be there if A is not there)? If that's the case, meaning you may reduce your list of dependencies to one single value, the algorithm would be much lighter.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I proof you it's not a tree. (A),(B),(C),(D),(E).    (A), (B) is independent. (C), (D) both depend on (A), (B). (E) depend on (C). See? The tree has to just one Root

Comment: I've talked about directed graph. With the new specification (that you didn't share at the beginning) it is indeed not a tree, but still a directed graph for which traversal algorithms exist. Can you answer to my other question instead? What is the meaning of B depends on A and C, and C depends on A? Can you assume that C depends on A and B depends on C, or are there cases where such multiple-dependency actually exist?

Comment: You're looking for something usually called a [Dependency Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph); one simple technique for solving them is to use a [Topological Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  This is relatively easy to writ in JS.  Let us know if you get stuck implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    function canRun(obj, readyIds) {
        // Without childs... can run
        if (!obj.children || obj.children.lenght === 0)
            return true;

        // If some req is not added yet... can't run
        for (let i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
            if (!readyIds[obj.children[i]])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    function getSortedList(list) {
        let readyIds = [];
        let listSorted = [];
        let someChanged = true;

        while (list.length > 0 && someChanged) {
            someChanged = false;

            for (let i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var item = list[i];

                if (canRun(item, readyIds)) {
                    list.splice(i, 1);
                    listSorted.push(item);
                    readyIds[item.id] = true;
                    someChanged = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return listSorted;
    }
```

canRun check when an item can be executed: it hasn't dependencies or all dependencies have been added before.

To sort the items, we iterate list removing the items that canRun and adding into listSorted. We need to do in a while because in each for we can add only the items without dependencies. someChanged is for security, in case some item can't be executed, to prevent infinite while. In a normal case, list become empty and listSorted have all items. If some item can't be executed, list have these items and listSorted, the items that can be executed.

Test code:

```
    var objA = {
        id: 1
    }
    var objB = {
        id: 2,
        children: [1, 3] //<== this is ID of objA and objC
    }
    var objC = {
        id: 3,
        children: [1] //<== this is ID of objA
    }

    let list = [objA, objB, objC];
    let listSorted = getSortedList(list);
```